# How to automatically check for content and save to a file?

Tags: php, file, save, external-process, automatic-updates

Hello,

I am calling few contents from my blog to my website, however when user goes to my website, every-time he use to come to my website the contents of the blogs are fetched and then get displayed. Which slow down the website performance.

Now i am calling my blog content to an external file which is fetching the content from my blog and storing it. And i call my content from that file to get displayed on my website.

My question is: **I want my external file (Which is storing the data in it) to automatically check for updates after every 12 hrs or say 24 hrs and save the content**, so that i don't need to manually run the script to update the content.

I am using PHP, so if you can help me doing this using PHP, it will be great. Thanks.

Comment: And search for "Caching". Also make sure you profiled your application and actually *know* that your current approach is too slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My approach to similar jobs is using up **cron** service(in Linux/UNIX, similar to Scheduled Tasks in Windows). My virtual host service provider have provided such options in its CPanel. You may also ask your service provider for assistance. **cron** can do jobs in intervals down to 1 minute.

To do the job, first code some scripts which I call a **trigger**, e.g: trigger.php, and look up in the control panel for cron jobs. For example:
[image]

(sorry for non-English pictures)

In the middle of the panel, you can set patterns for *MINUTES*, *HOURS*, *DAYS*, *MONTHS*, *YEARS* and enter your *COMMAND* scheduled to execute.
* means each, so if you set *MINUTES* to *(with all others left to *), it means every minute cron will run your command. If you set *MINUTES* to 5 with all others to *, cron will run in each hour's 5th minute. Other expressions, like setting *MINUTES* to */10 with *HOURS* as 1,5,7,9 , tells cron execute command during 1st, 5th, 7th, 9th hour of the day in which interval is 10 minutes.

**cron** is configurable under LINUX/UNIX shells. To do this, type

```
$ crontab -e
```

An editor will show up for modifications. Configurations are same as described above. When done, save and quit.

**cron** service is provided with a daemon program. So remember to check that this daemon does running on your system, command **top** will do.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I understand that we can use CRON to accomplish this job, could you please help me describing a bit. That how actually to implement it. Please :)